# Cannot inspect iOS 11 devices with Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, safari, ios11

I'm trying to debug what apparently is a CSS transform styling bug that only occurs on iOS 11 mobile devices.

But when I try to inspect these devices with Safari, **the device name shows briefly on the Develop menu and then disappears**.

I'm able to inspect a device running iOS 10 (an iPhone 6) normally, but then the actual issue I'm trying to debug does not occur.

Tried with two different devices running iOS 11 and multiple computers. Also different cables, including original Apple ones.

Mobile device: iPhone 7 11.0.2 (15A421), iPhone 7 11.0.3 (15A432)

Desktop device: MacBook Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73) and others

Safari: Version 10.1.1 (12603.2.4) and others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To inspect/detect iOS11 devices, use [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/)

Comment: For me Safari Technology Preview didn't help but when I upgraded iOS from 11.1 to 11.2.1 the standalone website appeared again as an inspectable in Safari 11.0.2.

Comment: Wasted hours trying to solve this. Can't believe this is the solution Actually I can. Really disliking apple these days. Thanks man!